# Display an empty field when NSTextField contents are 0

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I have an NSTextField which holds numeric (integer) values. There is a number formatter attached to the field. I want to display an empty field when the value of the field is set to 0 (zero). I think I tried every combination with the formatter, without luck so far. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with NSNumberFormatter. But you could make a subclass and implement `stringFromNumber:` something like this:

```
-(NSString *)stringFromNumber:(NSNumber *)number {
    NSNumber *zero = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    if ([number isEqualToNumber:zero])
        return @"";
    else
        return [super stringFromNumber:number];
}
```

**EDIT:**

I was wrong. You can do that with NSNumberFormatter:

```
[formatter setZeroSymbol:@""];
```